# Copy/paste plone portlets

Tags: plone

Is there any existing add-on that allows user to copy and paste context portlets?

If not - are there any contraindications to implement it?

Comment: I once created a custom code which allows you to "refer" portlets e.g. one instance of portlet is linked in many places of the site

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa do you have somewhere an example of that code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any addons which provide this feature.

The UI of manage portlet screen is kinda hard to add copy/cut/paste buttons so i will say try to by move all actions inside a drop down menu.

Actions on portlets are:

- move up / down (with condition on display)
- delete
- hide
- edit (click on title)

I know users which believe the 'x' is the action to hide the portlet  ... This is why I believe a dropdown menu with full text actions will be better than more icons.

```
--------------
portlet title

actions v
--------------
```

And the portlet title should not be a link.

Comment: my question was more about implementation contraindications rather then UI problems ;-)